# python, cómo hago que al introducir un valor que no sea un número en un int(input()) me muestre un mensaje de error personalizado en vez del de python

Tags: python

```
edad = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))

if edad > 0 and edad <= 120:
    if edad >= 18:
        iden = input("¿Tienes identificación oficial? (s/n): ")
        if iden == "s":
            print("Trámite de licencia concedido")
        elif iden == "n":
            print("No cumples los requisitos")
        else:
            print("Respuesta incorrecta")
    else:
        print("No cumples los requisitos")
else:
    print("Respuesta incorrecta")
```

al introducir una letra en la edad, necesito que me salga "Respuesta incorrecta" en vez de un error de python
si se es menor de edad o no se tiene identificación, no se cumple con el requisito de sacar licencia de manejo. si se cumple con la mayoría de edad y se tiene licencia, el trámite se concede. necesito hacer que al introducir un valor como "g" en la edad, me de un output de "no se cumplen los requisitos"

Comment: Utilizando la palabra reservada "raise" con la Frase de la exepcion que desees mostrar.

Answer (score 3):

Lo haces capturando la excepción con un bloque `try/except`

```py
try:
    edad = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))
except:
    print("no se cumplen los requisitos")
    exit()
```

El `exit` finaliza la ejecución del script, tambien puedes meter todo tu código dentro del `try` y olvidarte del `exit` pero en caso de ocurrir una excepción que no sea del `int(input())` también se ejecutará el `except`. Si solo quieres capturar la excepción de la conversión utiliza `except ValueError: ...`